# Why sudden Flutter APK size increase?

Tags: flutter

Why did I suddenly increase the size of the flutter APK by 7 to 30 MB? It seems that no new media files added, I only added the Image_Picker library, but I do not think the change in size is associated with it.

I would understand if the size had increased gradually, but no. On the same day, when assembling APK weighed 7 MB, and in a few days, with the next assembly, APK weighed at that time 22MB, now in general 30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the apk size using the `analyze-size` flag, run the following command to get a detailed report of the apk:

`flutter build apk --analyze-size`

You can also perform a deep-analysis using the Dart DevTools and the Size Tool from within it.

The size of you apk can also change a lot depending on whether you're using `release` or `debug` mode.

Using these tools you can find what exactly caused the app size to change.

For more information on the measuring the app size, visit this [doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/app-size)